# NUnit and Moles error

Tags: c#, nunit, moles

I am trying to run NUnit with Moles and I am getting a weird error and I am not quite sure why.

```
    [Test]
    [Moled]
    public void SendEmail_Test()
    {
        SIEmailService emailService = new SIEmailService
                                            {
                                                SendMailStringStringString = (email, subject, body) => { }
                                            };

        SIServiceLocator serviceLocator = new SIServiceLocator();
        serviceLocator.GetInstance(() => emailService);

        MLocatorFactory.GetInstance = (() => serviceLocator);


        IEmailservice = new EmailService();
        service.SendEmail("someone@there.com", null, null, null, DateTime.Now, null);
    }
```

Error:

[image: The security issue that is being thrown]

Any suggestions on how to fix this partially trusted caller issue???? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your tests assembly [AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.allowpartiallytrustedcallersattribute.aspx). But I am not sure why it requires this. May be you are running your tests from network share?

Comment: Nope no network share trying to set up example, to convience team to use Moles....not going well. Now learning more towards conviencing them to us MSTest because this is so annoying. I will look at your link thanks for fast reply.

Comment: OK so I tried adding [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] as an attribute to my test file and I am still getting the same error message.